# In the WPF MVVM pattern, I only have the model data bound to the ItemsControl Can I get the UIElement for that item?

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

In the WPF MVVM pattern, I only have the model data bound to the ItemsControl
Can I get the UIElement for that item?

However, because there are hundreds of ItemsControls, which ItemsControl contains
I do not know.

```
    void InitData()
    {
        GroupList = new ObservableCollection<GroupModel>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            GroupModel groupItem = new GroupModel() { GroupName = $"Group {i}" };
            groupItem.ItemList = new ObservableCollection<KeyValueModel>();
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 100; i2++)
            {
                groupItem.ItemList.Add(new KeyValueModel() { Key = string.Format("Key {0}", i2.ToString("000")), Value = string.Format("Value {0}", i2.ToString("000")) });
            }

            GroupList.Add(groupItem);
        }

        // Can I get the UIElement of the targetItem?
        KeyValueModel targetItem = GroupList.Last().ItemList.Last();
    }


<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GroupList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="12,0,12,0" />

                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="0,0,10,10">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="White" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Where do you want to get a reference to the UI element and what UI element?

Comment: Why do you want to get the UI item? And BTW your `WrapPanel` doesn't support `Virtualisation` which may cause performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator` may help you to achieve it, please refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.